# Make keyboard universal instead of per-app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur, input-source

When I switch input source it sometimes doesn't switch across all apps, using its previous setting on some apps and its new setting on the one I switched while using.

How do I make the input language just a global setting that doesn't care about what app is focussed?

Comment: Have you looked at system preferences > keyboard > input sources and made sure the box related to automatic switching of input sources is not checked?

Comment: @TomGewecke it is not checked